# Rails select opton using images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select

i have a select_tag in my rails form where i want to show images as option, i tried searching for a solution online but there is nothing quite good.

**my form**

```
<%= form.select :transport, ['Select an image', 'http://pngimg.com/uploads/tesla_car/tesla_car_PNG24.png', 'http://pluspng.com/img-png/png-hd-bike-ktm-duke-bike-png-download-1600.png' %>
```

i want something like this:
[click here](https://codepen.io/antonandoff/pen/PmQvBz)

Comment: OPTION tags does not accept images as content, only text, you need to use some plugin to mask the original select tag with a custom "select" tag using javascript and other elements.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of struggling to let Rails handle it, It's recommended to use JQuery to populate options in the drop-down list.

This link guides you through the process to do it.

[Click Here](https://makitweb.com/insert-image-in-dropdown-lists-with-jquery/)